# How to get more detail about the identifier of auto in iterator of C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

```
 void test()
 {
       vector <string> s={"hello world"};
       for(vector<string>::iterator it=s.begin();it!=s.end()&&!it->empty();it++)
      {
           for(auto it2=it->begin();it2!=it->end();it2++)//I don't konw  type of it2
           {
                *it2=toupper(*it2);
           }
       cout<<*it<<endl;
     }
}
```

In the first loop I can sure that iterator of type is `vector<string>::iterator`. I wonder what is type of the `it2` (I have already tried use `vector<string>::const`). And how can I get the more detail about which type did `auto` equal.

Comment: May I ask, why do you need to know?

Comment: `*(it)` is of type `std::string&` so check the type for [std::string::begin()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/begin) (no `const`) -> it's `std::string::iterator`

Comment: I  reading the 《C++ premier》in the third chapter and doing some practices of book. The problem asks to use iterator to achieve.And I first use auto but be curious about the specific type of iterator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`it` is an iterator into a `vector<string>`. Which means that `it` "points to" a `string`. So when you write `it->begin()` and `it->end()`, you're iterating over the `string`, which would make `it2` have type `std::string::iterator`. As smartly noted in the comments by [Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826746/how-to-get-more-detail-about-the-identifier-of-auto-in-iterator-of-c11/32826870?noredirect=1#comment53489877_32826870) and [Mr. Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826746/how-to-get-more-detail-about-the-identifier-of-auto-in-iterator-of-c11/32826870?noredirect=1#comment53490114_32826870), this type **does not matter**. It is simply the type of something that "points to" a `char` with which we can iterator over our `string`. This is one of the main selling points of `auto` - if the name of the type doesn't matter, don't clutter your code with it.

Note that since you never actually need iterators in your code, you could simply avoid them with a range-based for loop:

```
for (auto& str : s) {
    for (auto& chr: str) {
        chr = toupper(chr);
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you ever need to know the exact type of something, I'd recommend the following hack. Make a class template that takes a type but is never defined:

```
template <typename > struct TD; // for Type Description
```

And then just stick it in somewhere:

```
for (auto it2 = ... ) {
    TD<decltype(it2)> t;
    // ...
}
```

which would give the following error with gcc 5.2:

```
main.cpp:16:34: error: aggregate 'TD<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > t' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
                TD<decltype(it2)> t;
                                  ^
```

Notice that the compile error has the complete type of `it2` in it.

Comment: Also note that `string::iterator` as a type means little other than the result of `string.begin()`.  In a sense, `string::iterator` is a type *without information* beyond the expression that produced it.

Comment: @Yakk, indeed! A very good point that people who are "scared" of `auto` forget! Saying `string::iterator it2 = it->begin()` is no more useful than `auto it2 = it->begin()`, they both say "give me a variable of the type returned by `it->begin()`"